# Adding content via Siri to text files in Dropbox?

Tags: iphone, applescript, dropbox, siri

Recently, I decided to move a series of lists I keep in the Notes app (Groceries, Shopping, Movies to Watch, Local Bands we follow, Local Restaurants we like, etc.) to a Dropbox folder that I share with my wife on her Android phone, which is an excellent way to keep files in sync on all my devices.  However, I quickly discovered the drawback - I can no longer add content using Siri to those notes!

I've started searching for ways to hack-in some sort of syncing, or even appending, content in specific notes to text files in Dropbox.  So far, every way I've investigated has drawbacks.  There are launchd/Lingon solutions, really hacky Applescript folder actions (forcing file updates by deleting & replacing files), one-way appending using cron jobs & applescripts, etc..

Whether I use dropbox or some other content sharing management system - I would still have the same issue of not being able to tell siri to add stuff to the files...  Plus, the solution would have to work offline because we get no internet access in the Grocery store and various other places where we'd like to access the notes.

Anyone have a reliable straight-forward way to sync the content of Notes with text files in Dropbox?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: BTW, I know there are apps like OurGroceries.  Believe me, I've investigated a ton of list-sharing apps.  My favorite is UpWord, but it's not available on Android.  Second favorite is PlainText2, which is what I'm using now.  I like being able to edit the lists on my computer and I like that I can paste in lists from text documents.  To me, the entry method of OurGroceries is too limiting.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is possible. The notes app buries files deep in the mobile documents folder on the desktop.

I believe it uses some sort of IMAP protocol.

Comment: It does use IMAP, however the contents can be retrieved and manipulated via applescript.  If I put a lot of effort into it, I could script a sync myself, but that's a heck of a lot of work because you'd have to re-invent synchronization.